# How to check if element exists in another 3 dimensional array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

```
scheme = [['G', 'g', ''],
          ['R', 'c', ''],
          ['Y', 'r', '']]

blocks = [['C', 'R', 'Y', 'G', 'B'],
          ['b', 'r', 'c', 'g', 'y'],
          ['', '', '', '', '']]


for x in blocks[1]:
    if x not in scheme[0] + scheme[1] + scheme[2]:
        if blocks[0][blocks[0].index(x)] in scheme[0] + scheme[1] + scheme[2]:
            algo.append(f'{blocks[1].index(x) + 1} throw from blocks')
            blocks[1][blocks[1].index(x)] = ''
```

I need to check if the 0 element from blocks exists in scheme and 1 element from blocks doesn't exist in scheme, then

```
algo.append(f'{blocks[1].index(x) + 1} throw from blocks')
blocks[1][blocks[1].index(x)] = ''
```

But i got the error:

> if blocks[0][blocks[0].index(x)] in scheme[0] + scheme[1] + scheme[2]:
> ValueError: 'b' is not in list

Please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure that you copy and paste complete, exact error messages, formatted as code. Also, please make sure you understand that your code does not contain any arrays (they are *lists*) and that they are not 3-dimensional (you have a list of lists of strings). Also, please try to make it possible for others to understand exactly what the code is supposed to do. For example, show exactly what you want the output to be, for the specific input that you showed, and trace through the intended logic.

Comment: `x` is the elements in `blocks[1]`, which is `['b', 'r', 'c', 'g', 'y']`. In this iteration, `x` is `'b'`. Then you do `blocks[0].index(x)`. Why do you expect it to tell you that `['C', 'R', 'Y', 'G', 'B']` contains the string `'b'`? It doesn't. That's what the error is telling you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's giving you an error is because the strings are case sensitive.

Add the upper function to x.

```
index(x.upper())
```